# Identifying the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_{9}[x]/(x^2-3,3x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings, polynomial-rings

> I want to know if there is a simple form of the ring 
>   $$R=\mathbb{Z}_{9}[x]/(x^2-3,3x)$$

I tried to start with the equations $3x\equiv0$ and $x^2\equiv 3$. So, $3x^2\equiv 0$ and $3x^2\equiv 9$. The ideal $I=(x^2-3,3x)=((x-3)^2)$.

I don't know if is true. Also, the form I got is not simple enough. If my solution was true, what is the ring 
$$R=\mathbb{Z}_{9}[x]/((x-3)^2)$$

Comment: Note that in this quotient, all elements are of the form $a+bx$ where $0\leq a\leq 8; 0\leq b\leq 2$

Comment: @cello Looks like you meant $a$ and $b$ the other way around? 3 choices for $a$?

Comment: Yes yes @rschwieb

Comment: That is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2-3,3x)$ since $x^2 = 3$ and $3x= 0$ implies $9= 3x^2 = (3x)x = 0$. Then $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2-3,3x) \cong \mathbf Z[\sqrt{3}]/(3\sqrt{3})$, which is $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{3}]/(\sqrt{3}^3)$. This is a ring of order $|{\rm N}(\sqrt{3}^3)| = 27$.

Comment: @KCd I don't get it . Also, why there are only few choices for $a$.

Comment: The ring $\mathbf Z_9$ means $\mathbf Z/9\mathbf Z$ and this implies $\mathbf Z_9[x] \cong \mathbf Z[x]/(9)$, so $\mathbf Z_9[x]/(x^2-3,3x) \cong \mathbf Z[x]/(9,x^2-3,3x)$. The calculations in my previous comment show that $9$ is actually inside $(x^2-3,3x)$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$: explicitly, $9 = x(3x) - 3(x^2-3)$. From $(9,x^2-3,3x) = (x^2-3,3x)$ we get $\mathbf Z_9[x]/(x^2-3,3x) \cong \mathbf Z[x]/(x^2-3,3x)$. If you have further questions about what I wrote, speak to a nearby math professor. (Not sure what you mean by "few choices for $a$, since I wrote $a$ nowhere.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the question about $a$ to @cello ..Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this ring has a simpler representation.

However, it has a nice property: The only ideals are $(x^0) = R$, $(x^1) = (x)$, $(x^2) = (3)$, $(x^3) = \{0\}$. Therefore, $R$ is a *chain ring* as the lattice of ideals forms a chain.

Thus $R$ may be thought of as a brother of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}$, which is another chain ring of the same order.